# JavaDoc generated doc lists classes and methods twice

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a simple java project and I use JavaDoc to generate documentation.
From when I created a package for my classes, JavaDoc began to generate links twice.
On the class list on the left every class is listed twice.
In the index-all page as well every class name and method is listed twice.

Even method that are not overridden o overloaded.

I come from C# and I intended to use package as the equivalent of C# namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, where javadoc was generating output with classes listed twice (duplicated).

I found my problem was that I was including both a -sourcepath and the package name. For example:

`javadoc -d ./output_dir com.companyname.security.securedata sourcepath src/tre-jvm/classlib/src/com/companyname/security/securedata/*`

When actually, I only needed to include the -sourcepath and path argument, i.e.

`javadoc -d ./output_dir sourcepath src/tre-jvm/classlib/src/com/companyname/security/securedata/*`

To generate the javadocs output.

Comment: Any idea for those experiencing this with `mvn site` and javadoc plugin? I don't see anything outstanding in pom.xml :(

Comment: I don't even remember writing this answer, and only worked with this a short period of time. :) Good luck though.

Comment: I noticed it is only the case with Corretto 1.8 I had.