# Maven JavaDoc listed classes twice

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I am using the javadoc maven plugin and it creates the correct javadoc package, but all classes are created twice.

#### Maven dependency:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

#### My build code

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Can anyone help me please, what am I missing here?

[image]

command usage for doc generation

```
mvn clean install -Dresources="FirstProject/example_API"
```

Comment: The first question: Why do you use a maven plugin as a dependency? (maven-surefire-pugin)? Does not make sense...Furthermore it would be helpful having a github or alike project and how you called Maven?

Comment: updated! wrong dependency mentioned before.
2nd updated maven command.

Comment: One reason why you might have this problem is the Java version that you are using. It looks like this problem might happen if Java 1.8 Corretto is used. I checked it locally and indeed Javadoc was duplicated when I used it (this is also mentioned in the comments of this conversation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843475/javadoc-generated-doc-lists-classes-and-methods-twice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed the same problem and came upon a solution after enabling debug on the maven-javadoc-plugin maven plugin and seeing what it's doing. Specifically setting the sourcepath as shown below fixed the double listing problem for me and I've tried this on multiple version of Corretto 8 as well as Temurin 8. All had the double listing problem because it's an issue with the javadoc tool itself but setting the sourcepath manually fixed it for me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me... awesome solution :)

Comment: It is not an issue with the javadoc tool, it is an issue with the Maven Javadoc Plugin. Also nothing to do with which JDK distribution you are using. Don't peddle such story. (that would indeed be a first if that was the case). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70767572/1504556) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in recent versions of the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/). The bug is known as [MJAVADOC-700](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-700). It is dead easy to reproduce.

Downgrading to version `3.2.0` of the plugin fixes the problem. Setting the `sourcepath` explicitly is an alternative fix.